# How to select/highlight an image by double clicking in the same way as text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to find out how to 'select' an image. That is if you were to double click on any text on this page, that word will be highlighted/selected.

Is it possible to do the same with an image.

https://jsfiddle.net/eL6my246/

```html
<img src="http://www.free.fr/freebox/im/logo_free.png" style="max-width:200px;" />
<p>
  Here is some content. Double click a word to 'select' it. Now try
  with the image and notice it doesn't get selected.
</p>
```

If you click in the result pane of the JSFiddle (the page where the HTML is rendered) and on your keyboard do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> (select all) you can see the image is selected (it goes in blue). How can I select the image by single (or double) clicking the image?

Comment: *"How can I select the image by single clicking"* - Single, or double as in the question title?

Comment: @nnnnnn either actually. I'm just interested in selecting the image...

Answer (score 2):

Here is a small example on programmatically doing selection via javascript. It is interesting to see the documentation for [**window.getSelection()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getSelection) and also the [**Range**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range) class API

```js
var btnToggleSelection = document.getElementById('toggleSelection');
btnToggleSelection.imgSelected = false;

btnToggleSelection.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

  if (this.imgSelected) {
    /* deselect image */
    clearSelection();
    this.innerHTML = "Select";
  } else {
    /* select image */
    var s = window.getSelection();
    var r = document.createRange();
    r.selectNode(document.images[0]);
    s.addRange(r);
    this.innerHTML = "Deselect";
  }

  this.imgSelected = !this.imgSelected;
});

function clearSelection() {
  if (window.getSelection) {
    if (window.getSelection().empty) { // Chrome
      window.getSelection().empty();
    } else if (window.getSelection().removeAllRanges) { // Firefox
      window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
    }
  } else if (document.selection) { // IE
    document.selection.empty();
  }
}
```

```html
<img src="http://www.free.fr/freebox/im/logo_free.png" style="max-width:200px;" />
<button id="toggleSelection">Select</button>
```

Check the code and make it fit your needs. Let me know if you need more help. Good luck !

Comment: Oddly, this appears to have some browser issues - using MS Edge, it does not appear to work but this is interesting to read (and I'm sure I'm OK to figure out the changes needed to get it to work in Edge)

Answer (score 1):

Just add an attribute to `img` tag `contenteditable` it will allow user to select on doubleclick.

Comment: I don't believe this is true for a browsers? Yes for Chrome, but not for IE or  Edge https://jsfiddle.net/eL6my246/1/

Comment: i checked for browser compatibility of contenteditable.. it shows that it work in IE

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes#attr-contenteditable

Comment: I provided a link in my first comment. Try it! contentEditble works fine in DIV tags for example, but *appears* to not with images for IE/Edge